# How to prevent my wrapper div to move when i resize window?

Tags: html, css

The content of my wrapper div is moving anytime I resize my browser window's height (or when I open the console log) to keep up with the frame. This cause some elements to overlap with others.

I've tried to add `width` `height` `min-width` and `min-height` properties to the wrapper without success.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: can you post a fiddle or your html and css?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand your problem if you can share your code example